# How does windows 10 avoid memory fragmentation?

Tags: mmu

I tried a test program that just allocated 3 bytes to a large array of pointers and the virtual addresses returned from malloc were only 0x20 apart (32 bytes). Now I'm familiar with most algorithms for avoiding fragmentation, which usually involve playing around with the MMU page table entries. So, what I expected was a page size of 4K or something like that. I'm more familiar with linux or embedded RTOS solutions to these problems, but when it comes to windows, I'm unsure. Does anyone out there know what Windows does that allows it to allocate memory with this kind of tight resolution (32 bytes) instead of the more usual 4K page sizes? Just curious as to what windows is doing there. Is it that they have a special block of memory for small allocations and then do some kind of garbage collection later? Interested in any feedback. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you allocate memory, with VirtualAlloc or similar? VirtualAlloc rounds up to the nearest page size, so even if you ask for 32 bytes, you'll get 4K. If you're just writing a normal program, though, you won't actually ever be allocing from Windows directly - you'll be using your RTL's memory manager. This is true on Linux too. Since your addresses are so close, I'd bet this is what's happening: the MM allocated memory, and is now giving you free memory out of it.

Comment: As my text says, I used "malloc"....I used gcc in cygwin...quick and simple. I'm not familiar enough with windows internals to know if the runtime library does what you are saying or not. I'd defer to your knowledge. So you are saying that it's grabbing 32 bytes at a time from a big block allocated by the RTL. So, when I call malloc, it uses the RTL to grab the block. The smallest it allows is 32bytes, and whenever it goes up to a page size (4K or whatever), the RTL grabs another page from the main MM. The MM places them contiguously so it appears to me like they are all sequentially together.

Comment: I don't know enough about GCC's RTL, and how the memory manager works. But the MM will get memory from Windows, and will then return a pointer to some of it when you call malloc. Internally, the MM may do all sorts of things with its memory to reduce fragmentation; it may keep separate heaps for small and medium allocations, for example.